# Remove html tags when an excel file is imported to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an excel file with more than 1000 items. Few columns contains text with html tags.

So I wanted to ask, what would be the different approaches that can be used so that when we are importing this excel data to SharePoint list, it should not include those html tags in the text.

Also  the challenge is that the data in multiline rich text colunm should appear as it is provided in the excel file.

Like if one line of text is bold and next line is italic, then when we import it to list then it should add in similar way that means one line bold and then italic to rich text column.

Comment: I don't think you can do this during the import. You have to either remove them in excel before the export or remove them in SharePoint after the import. In Excel, you can select all the data and use replace (ctrl+f), then replace all the html tags with nothing, so it'll remove them. In SharePoint, you can either run a powershell script or use column validation / calculation. This really depends on the data you have :)